# building asp.net mvc from sources

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to build my asp.net mvc project with original  mvc sources. All works fine (solution is building and working as expected) except desiging razor cshtml-pages. Intellisence do not understand command @model. Look at screenshot - it explain my problem.
Is there any way to fix this problem?

Screenshot http://i60.fastpic.ru/big/2013/1005/8a/36343e4b9a7f850b6dc290ec7501978a.png
at the left - solution with ASP.NET MVC bilded from sources,
at the right - solution using original MVC assemblies from GAC

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need the @ symbol there and also i think it should be Model so:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Value
}
```

Comment: Look at the first line. It highligted red.  Then I referenced at gac version of asp.net - I have no problem

Comment: No luck... new screenshot http://i60.fastpic.ru/big/2013/1005/54/36a07224416f4da300da3e38be752254.png

Comment: have you added references to razor in the web config?

Comment: sure.. i use original web.config created by VS, just remove assembly version and public token... maybe VS designer wants strongnamed assembly for designer?